# Removing all punctuation from a set of words, or writing all unique words from txt file into a set (without punctuation) in c++

Tags: c++, file, set

I needed a program that puts all unique words from a txt file into a set, and so i've found this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string fileName{ "unique.text" };

int main() {

// Open the source file and check, if it could be opend and there is no failure
if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream(fileName); sourceFileStream) {

    // Read all words (everything delimited by a white space) into a set
    std::set words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(sourceFileStream), {});

    // Now we have a set with all unique words. Show this on the screen
    std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
// If  we could not open the source file
else {
    std::cerr << "\nCould not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

My problem is that i needed just the words without punctuation but this code delimits the file only by spaces. I've tried doing erase and remove_if but they dont really work with sets, there's probably a way to just make a separate set with the right condition but i coudn't figure it out or find anything it.

Comment: You either need a transform iterator to remove punctuation, or create another set with cleaned word, or remove word from set when "dirty" to re-add them cleaned.

Comment: Values in set are immutable.

Comment: Yeah i figured another set would work, i coudnt figure out how to create a new set that would copy all words from the first set while also removing the hanging commas and what not. Removing and re-adding the problematic words back woudn't work because i need the sorted order that sets provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code has been originally written by me, I will answer your question.

We simply use a `std::transform`, to modify the strings received from the file and remove all punctuation.

The `std::transform` will iterate over all strings read from the stream, and then passes each string to a lambda. The lambda will modify the string and return the result. The result will be inserted into the `std::set`.

Removing the punctuation can be easily done, because we have a function `std::ispunct` that will identify all the special characters.

Then we use a combination of `std::remove` if and `std::string.erase`, to modify the string.

That is rather straightforward.

Please see the new solution below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string fileName{ "r:\\unique.txt" };

int main() {

    // Open the source file and check, if it could be opend and there is no failure
    if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream(fileName); sourceFileStream) {

        // Here we will store all our words
        std::set < std::string> words{};

        // Read all words (everything delimited by a white space) into a set
        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(sourceFileStream), {}, std::inserter(words, words.begin()),
            [](std::string s) {s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ispunct), s.end()); return s; });

        // Now we have a set with all unique words. Show this on the screen
        std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
    // If  we could not open the source file
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nCould not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To be compiled with c++ 17

Comment: Woah thank you! Small world,i wanted to ask how does std::ispunct work, my compiler doesnt see it as a function, i tried adding () or (s) after it but it didnt really work. Is there something wrong with my setup? (i am using c++ 17)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include <cctype>. I updated the answer

Comment: I tried including the <cctype> earlier, after googling what the function does does, but the compiler still doesnt seem to work it properly. I get: "no matching function for call to 'remove_if' "and "no instance of function template std::remove_if matches the argument list".

Comment: Sorry again. Updated again. Tested with clang and gcc with flages ````--std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic```` On my machine it works now.